# To remove screen_reader_text coming in h2 from the_posts_pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using twentyfifteen theme and for pagination , i have used the_posts_pagination and want to remove h2 tag and text

I have tried but it just remove "Post navigation"text,not h2 tag

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
  'prev_text'          => __( '&nbsp;', 'twentyfifteen' ),
  'next_text'          => __( '&nbsp;', 'twentyfifteen' ),
  'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',//Page
  'screen_reader_text' => __( '&nbsp;' )
) );
```

Pl help me. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

It is not clear why you need to get rid of the h2 tag, since it has class `screen-reader-text` which, in the standard twentyfifteen theme is clipped so that it does not display.

But, if you do need to do it the easiest way is use the get_the_posts_pagination() function to get the HTML and remove it before displaying:

```
$nav = get_the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text'          => __( '&nbsp;', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'next_text'          => __( '&nbsp;', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'screen_reader_text' => __( 'A' )
    ) );
$nav = str_replace('<h2 class="screen-reader-text">A</h2>', '', $nav);
echo $nav;
```

[Reference is here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination) for more...

Comment: On the other hand, I understand Bhumi Shah's need well: I don't want a tag in the markup that I don't need, especially since it is an H2, an important tag also for search engines.

Answer (score 2):

Use this. it works for me

```
function the_clean_pagination()
{
 $thePagination = get_the_posts_pagination();

 echo preg_replace('~(<h2\\s(class="screen-reader-text")(.*)[$>])(.*)(</h2>)~ui', '', $thePagination);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php the_posts_pagination(array( 'screen_reader_text'=> '&nbsp;'));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old but - if you go to this [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2343) and search for the function the_posts_navigation()
you will see the following arg 'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ), 
so we need to override

```
the_posts_pagination(array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'prev_text' => '<span class="prev-page">Prev</span>',
    'next_text' => '<span class="next-page">Next</span>',
    'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
    'before_page_number' => '',
));
```

Just make sure to add space in it to return empty. Not __( ' ' ).
Another option is to use filter and do our own template for the navigation hook "navigation_markup_template" . You can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609280/how-to-customize-get-the-post-navigation-in-theme/29610080)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned wanting to remove the h2 tag and text. But for accessibility it is helpful to keep the h2 with class `screen-reader-text`.
[This WordPress article on accessibility](https://make.wordpress.org/accessibility/handbook/markup/the-css-class-screen-reader-text/) shows how to hide the `Post navigation` text visually but keep it available to screen readers.

```
/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$nav = str_replace('<h2 class="screen-reader-text">A</h2>', '', $nav);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in function.php

```
function sanitize_pagination($content) {
  // Remove h2 tag
  $content = preg_replace('#<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>#si', '', $content);
  return $content;
}

add_action('navigation_markup_template', 'sanitize_pagination');
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove *screen_reader_text* I simply added
`'screen_reader_text'=>' '` in the *the_posts_pagination* function.

It worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old post, but another solution is to just hide it in the css:

.screen-reader-text{
    display: none
}

Simple, dirty, effective!

Comment: i DID say it was dirty! technically the text would still be in the markup, so might still get SEO'd?? AND no worse that replacing the field with blank string, so why the -1??!