# How to customize get_the_post_navigation in theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

`get_the_post_navigation()` function is defined inside `wp-includes/link-template.php`

How can I override it in my theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_the_post_navigation` does not utilize any filters so there is no easy way to modify or override all of its output.

While `get_the_post_navigation` does not apply any filter itself, it does call functions that do apply filter. Specifically [`get_adjacent_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post_link/):

```
return apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $output, $format, $link, $post );
```

Hooking into that filter will allow you to override some, but not all, of the output. `get_the_post_navigation` also uses [`_navigation_markup`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_navigation_markup/) which does not apply any filters. That portion of the output cannot be overridden.

You could [request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Development_Planning#Process_For_Feature_Requests) that a filter be added to that function. It would be a simple update and it would enable you to override all of the output.

```
function _navigation_markup( $links, $class = 'posts-navigation', $screen_reader_text = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $screen_reader_text ) ) {
        $screen_reader_text = __( 'Posts navigation' );
    }

    $template = '
    <nav class="navigation %1$s" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text">%2$s</h2>
        <div class="nav-links">%3$s</div>
    </nav>';

    //Add this line
    $template = apply_filters('navigation_markup_template', $template);

    return sprintf( $template, sanitize_html_class( $class ), esc_html( $screen_reader_text ), $links );
}
```

An easier solution might just be to create your own post navigation function, and then replace all references to `get_the_post_navigation` in your theme with your function.